# Canonical Question for High Load Average on Linux?

Tags: discussion

This morning yet another "Why is my load average so high?" question popped up in the Vote to close queue.

I've seen this question asked 80 different ways since I joined a couple years ago, this *must* but a duplicate.

But I can't seem to find one that seems to be canonical. Is there a canonical question for load averages? Anyone have a suggested candidate?

Answer (score 6):

I propose we convert this to a proper Canonical Linux Load Average question:

[How to understand the memory usage and load average in linux server](https://serverfault.com/questions/67759/how-to-understand-the-memory-usage-and-load-average-in-linux-server)

Suggestions? Questions? Catcalls from the Peanut Gallery in the Comms Room?

Comment: I'd rather see a question that's *just* about load average (since [we already have one about memory usage](http://serverfault.com/questions/449296/why-is-linux-reporting-free-memory-strangely) that links to two other questions with more detail.) Memory usage and Load Average are independent: I can easily create a load average over 1000 while using only a small amount of memory, or chew up all of a machine's RAM while maintaining a load average of near zero...

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep looking.

Comment: nothing wrong with creating one if you don't find any decent ones (it also gives us the opportunity to craft a good, correct answer and pad it with votes which is useful if the answers on the existing questions aren't really great)

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking this would be difficult to accomplish because there's literally hundreds of different reasons/ways that high load averages can result from.

The article Adrian linked is a good start. Explanations on *what* each average means, some cases of *when* the load average will spike (actual CPU usage, I/O load, etc) and *how* to diagnose a high load problem to effectively resolve the problem.

Tagging relavent questions would be a good way to gather some use cases for references when creating the question as well. Maybe something like [load-average](/questions/tagged/load-average)?

Comment: As there are hundred of reasons why, without extended back and forth with an OP it's really difficult to provide a solution hence having a canonical Q&A giving general guidance is a good thing.

Comment: True. I think the best way would be to find some good questions and cases to have a Q&A built up.